# Is it possible to change the default comment string in Octave GUI?

Tags: octave, octave-gui

In Octave GUI Editor the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut comments the selected lines out with the Octave default string `##`. But I share my code with other colleagues who use MATLAB. I was wondering if I could change the above keyboard shortcut and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to use the MATLAB commenting character `%` by default? I'm aware of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut where one can choose the string, but that is not very handy given the muscle memory and the extra step.

**P.S.** I posted this question also [here](https://discord.com/channels/384316553497280512/723625266261393488/816351878932594758) on the unofficial Octave Discord channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I think I found the solution, and it was way easier than what I had anticipated. Basically, the Octave GUI team had already thought of that. Just go to Edit > Preference, and then in the Comments (Octave) section, select the `%` option:

[image]